# Has anyone implemented the TestFlight SDK in a Flash Builder or Flash Professional project?

Tags: flash, sdk, flash-builder, testflight

Has anyone managed to get this to work with a FB or Flash Pro Project?  I am looking to use the enhanced features of TestFlight for an iPad app.

The TestFlight Software Development Kit (SDK) is a library that can be added to any iOS app for tracking analytics in beta/ internal testing and can also be used with apps in production (available in the App Store).

http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829549-what-is-the-testflight-sdk-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the NativeExtension: a wrapper around the SDK. Check this link and make sure you dot eh step described in the last comment:

http://extensionsforair.com/extensions/test-flight/

I'm using this to distribute builds of 2 Flash Builder apps to a team.